# Add dynamically object variable in existing state in reactjs (Using functional components)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm new in reactjs and creating small project, I used functional component not class components and used store for state. I have added some state variable and want to add array of object in exiting state, I tried but it not working. Below is my store file where set state:

```
export const initialState = {
  validationTally: 0,
  token: '',
  multiForm : []
  }

  // action types
const SET_VALIDATION_TALLY = 'SET_VALIDATION_TALLY';
const SET_TOKEN = 'SET_TOKEN';
const SET_MULTIFORM = 'SET_MULTIFORM';

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VALIDATION_TALLY:
          return {
            ...state,
            validationTally: state.validationTally + 1
          };
        case SET_TOKEN:
          return {
            ...state,
            token: action.payload
          };
        case SET_MULTIFORM:
          return {
            ...state,
            multiForm: action.payload
        };
    }
}

export const setValidationTally = () => ({
  type: SET_VALIDATION_TALLY
});

export const setToken = payload => ({
  type: SET_TOKEN,
  payload
});

export const setMultiForm = payload => ({
  type: SET_MULTIFORM,
  payload
});
```

I want to add object in state variable "multiForm" dynamically, when someone enter value 2 I want to add two object in "multiForm" like below

```
export const initialState = {
  validationTally: 0,
  app: '',
  token: '',
  multiForm : [{
    firstName : '',   
    lastName :''
  },
  {
    firstName : '',   
    lastName :''
  }]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `action.payload` for `SET_MULTIFORM` action contains the number of fields to be added, you can simply map over the array items and add to the existing fields

```
case SET_MULTIFORM:
      return {
        ...state,
        multiForm: [...state.multiForm, ...Array.from({ length: action.payload }).map(() => ({firstName: '', lastName: ''}))]
    };
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham 
Code worked but its not working inside the return braces, Its worked like this
case SET_MULTIFORM:
    [...state.multiForm] = [];
    [...state.multiForm, ...Array.from({ length: action.payload }).map(() => ({firstName: '', lastName: ''}))];
    return {
      ...state,
      multiForm: [...state.multiForm, ...Array.from({ length: action.payload }).map(() => ({firstName: '', lastName: ''}))]
  };